# Cross domain iframe widget design (State of the art approach)

Tags: javascript, iframe, widget

Im designing an application to be distributed in the form of a **widget**.

Just a simple piece of code (javascript + html) to be embedded on the client site. This code renders an iframe and inside of it I will load a web app that is on **my domain**.

Some interactions on this iframe fires events, one of these events needs to display a popup, something like lightbox, but as you know this thing will be inside the iframe and I dont have space inside to display it correctly, so I think the solution will be to call the popup on the _parent.

If so far you agree with (if not please tell me your suggestions) I will need to communicate from the iframe to the parent to fire the event. Is there a light (no jquery client side preferable) reliable, and simple way to call a javascript function in the _parent from another javascript function inside a cross-domain iframe ?

So far I've been experimenting with [this](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-postmessage/docs/files/jquery-ba-postmessage-js.html) and it seems to work fine, but it needs jquery on the client side. So my two main concern are:

**Will you use the same approach im using here to solve this issue?**

**How will you solve this without jquery?** (a code example will be great!)

Comment: Just wondering if you got anywhere with this?  I'd be interested in the solution also.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating a simple api and using jsonp ajax client-server communication ?
You wont have to worry about iframes this way...

Take a look of this basic api creation tutorial in case you need more info: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5pXxS0y4bg

Comment: Please, take in consideration the premise, i need the iframe.